# How to add hindi font in ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I am using ckeditor in my website and want to write in hindi by chosing option from languages.But i dont know what should i do for that ? Or how to write in hindi or which font i should add to select hindi font and then write in hindi in it.

Answer (score 0):

The font you use while typing in CKEditor, or any application online or offline, depends on what language packs you have installed in your computer. This is beyond our (CKSource) control. You could use something like [this application](http://specials.msn.co.in/ilit/Bengali.aspx) to add a language tool to your web browser but I don't know how it will interact with CKEditor.

Comment: i have added a code to write in hindi in ckeditor,please tell me what should i correct about it.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a code to write in hindi language please tell me whether it is correct or not.My Font file is Kruti.ttf
code of config.js is :-

```
config.font_names = 'Hindi/Kruti;' + config.font_names;
```

and code in content.css is :-

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'Kruti';
    src: url('Kruti.eot');
    src: local("Hindi"), url("Kruti.TTF") format("truetype");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```

Please correct me if this code is wrong.